# How to serialise Haskell ADTs as tidy JSON, using Aeson?

Tags: json, haskell, serialization, algebraic-data-types, aeson

I've spent some time playing around with Aeson, but I can't get Algebraic Data Types to serialise nicely.

What I've tried is:

```
data Attach = Attach { tel :: String }
              deriving (Show)
$(deriveJSON defaultOptions ''Attach)

data Fix = Fix { lat :: Double, lng :: Double }
              deriving (Show)
$(deriveJSON defaultOptions ''Fix)

data MsgIn = AttachMsg Attach
           | FixMsg    Fix
           deriving (Show)
$(deriveJSON defaultOptions ''MsgIn)

data MsgIn2 = MsgIn2 { attach :: Maybe Attach, fix :: Maybe Fix }
            deriving (Show)
$(deriveJSON defaultOptions ''MsgIn2)

someFunc :: IO ()
someFunc = do
  let attach = Attach "+447890"
  let reply = AttachMsg attach
  BL.putStrLn (encode reply)
  let reply2 = MsgIn2 (Just attach) Nothing
  BL.putStrLn (encode reply2)
```

The output is:

```
{"tag":"AttachMsg","contents":{"tel":"+447890"}}
{"attach":{"tel":"+447890"},"fix":null}
```

The output I'm looking for is:

```
{"attach":{"tel":"+447890"}}
```

but from the `MsgIn` type, rather than `MsgIn2`.

(The output of `MsgIn2` gets quite close, but it's got an explicit `null`.)

Is there a way of doing this in Aeson?

---

Update:

I added:

```
instance ToJSON MsgIn3 where
  toJSON (AttachMsg3 (Attach tel)) = object ["attach" .= object ["tel" .= tel]]
...
let reply3 = AttachMsg3 attach
BL.putStrLn (encode reply3)
```

and got the answer I wanted: `{"attach":{"tel":"+447890"}}`.

@bheklilr is there a way to use Attach's (already defined) serialisation, instead of defining it again?

I've tried some nonsense syntax, but understandably it doesn't compile:

```
instance ToJSON MsgIn3 where
  toJSON (AttachMsg3 (Attach tel)) = object ["attach" .= (toJSON :: Attach)]
```

Comment: You could just write the `ToJSON` and `FromJSON` instances manually to get exactly what you want: `toJSON (AttachMsg (Attach tel)) = object ["attach" .= object ["tel" .= tel]]`, and similarly for `FixMsg`.  The `parseJSON` implementation wouldn't be much more difficult.

Comment: @bheklilr Thanks, that was really useful.  Could you make it into an answer?  Could you see my updated question...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use custom options instead of defaultOptions. You can get the right structure by using `sumEncoding = ObjectWithSingleField`, which reduces your first example to `{"AttachMsg":{"tel":"+447890"}}`. You can then customize the constructor tags by using `constructorTagModifier = myConstructorTag` and by writing a function `myConstructorTag` that customizes the names to your liking (e.g. AttachMsg -> attach).

As an example, you'll get the output you want by writing this into a separate module, importing it, and using `myOptions` instead of `defaultOptions`:

```
myConstructorTag :: String -> String
myConstructorTag "AttachMsg" = "attach"
myConstructorTag x = x

myOptions :: Options
myOptions = defaultOptions {sumEncoding = ObjectWithSingleField, constructorTagModifier = myConstructorTag}
```

A separate module is needed here because of Template Haskell. There's probably a way to define myConstructorTag and myOptions in a better way to satisfy the needs of TH, but I have absolutely no idea how to do that.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like the right answer - it's getting late, so I'll try it tomorrow.

Comment: Works perfectly - separate file for defining options isn't a problem.

Answer (score 4):

You can get aeson to skip null fields automatically. I usually do this in combination with the `DeriveGeneric` extension:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings, DeriveGeneric #-}

import Data.Aeson
import Data.Aeson.Types
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as BL
import GHC.Generics

data Attach = Attach { tel :: String } deriving (Show, Generic)

data Fix = Fix { lat :: Double, lng :: Double } deriving (Show, Generic)

data Msg = Msg { attach :: Attach, fix :: Maybe Fix } deriving (Show, Generic)

instance ToJSON Attach
instance ToJSON Fix
instance ToJSON Msg where
    toJSON = genericToJSON (defaultOptions { omitNothingFields = True })

main = do
    let attach = Attach "+447890"
        reply  = Msg attach Nothing
    BL.putStrLn (encode reply)
```

which gives you:

```
*Main> main
{"attach":{"tel":"+447890"}}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I didn't explain myself clearly enough.  I want the output `{"attach":{"tel":"+447890"}}` from the original `MsgIn` data type.

Comment: This is still useful info, even if it doesn't answer the question, so I'm upvoting it anyway.